# ASP: want to host my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-hosting

I have a project in `ASP.NET`. I want to host it on internet, for this purpose I have uploaded all the files and my database [Here](http://amit12x-001-site1.smarterasp.net/PageCommon/index.aspx). 
but when i try to login , it shows error like this 
[image]
I haven't made any changes in my web.config file. like in my `web.cofig` file, my server name is AMIT-PC.

when i added `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` inside system.web, then it got error like this 
[image]
this is my connection string
         
            
          
    should i change it.

my whole web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connect" connectionString="server=AMIT-PC;database=OnlineLibrary;uid=sa;pwd=12345"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/PageUser/login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="connect" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="connect" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="connect" applicationName="/"/>
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: In which folder you have to upload files..

Comment: you have to find out what that error is.

Comment: As this error message says, add the <customErrors mode="Off"/> line to the system.web sub-section of the configuration section in the web.config to see what the error message is.

Comment: On your local machine (NOT on your public server) edit your web.config and set customErrors to "Off" as it explains in the error page and the exact exception will show up.

Comment: This doesn't really belong on SO.. The login page is working fine for me though.

Comment: it show only when i try to login .should i change the name of server

Comment: Find out what the error is. That's the first thing you need to do.

Comment: I see that your site is working fine. Please just customErrors to "Off" if you receive above error message to see the error message details

Comment: see my edited question . i have added <customErrors mode="Off"/> , but  problem is unsolved

Comment: You've put it in the wrong place. It needs to go *inside* `system.web`.

Comment: you have to put your code in httpdoc folder..

Comment: @AntP : sir now edited my code.

Comment: Looks like your database credentials are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql credentials going wrong some where. You are getting the error below
either your credentials are wrong or below problem
check the manage pipe tcpip etc configurations if they are allowed in sql server configuration manager

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

Comment: uid and pwd in connection string is of my sqlserver.